# Error when calling IBM MQ client from inside Docker container

Tags: asp.net, windows, docker, .net-core, ibm-mq

I developed a sample ASP.Net 4.8 application which is using IBM MQ client `amqmdnetstd.dll` (version 9.3.4.1)

IBM MQ client is not installed on machine, and I have just referenced this DLL in Visual Studio and when I press F5 then it works fine.

But when I publish the app and run it inside Docker container then it throws following exception:

```
Error Message: The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception. 

Stack Trace:
    at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable properties)
    at StudentManagementSystem.Classes.Middleware.CreateQueueManager() in C:\Code\StudentManagementSystem\StudentManagementSystem\Classes\Middleware.cs:line 37 Inner Exception: System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
    at System.IO.Path.NewNormalizePath(String path, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
    at IBM.WMQ.MQClientCfg.CheckForMqclientIniFileChanges()
    at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment..ctor(NmqiPropertyHandler nmqiPropertyHandler)
    at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiFactory.GetInstance(NmqiPropertyHandler properties)
    at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..cctor()
```

Why the application works from Visual Studio but not from Docker container? That `amqmdnetstd.dll` is present in bin directory.

Comment: Try creating an empty mqclient.ini file in the directory were the application is ran from, you may need to set the environment variable MQCLNTCF to point to the full path and name of the empty file.

Comment: Where is the queue manager running?

Comment: There is no queue manager running. I just wanted to see if I can reference the DLL and use it. On using it in Visual Studio, it correctly throws error `MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE` but when publishing it in IIS on my machine or inside Docker container, it throws different error which I have mentioned above.

Comment: Martin please see and try my suggestion.   There is a defect and it fails without this file present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I developed a sample ASP.Net 4.8 application which is using IBM MQ
> client amqmdnetstd.dll (version 9.3.4.1)

You should be following the IBM MQ 9.3 System Requirements for Windows. You are using MQ v9.3.4.1, so you need to use .NET v6.

See: [Requirements for IBM MQ classes for .NET](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=windows-hardware-software-requirements-systems#q008450___netcore__title__1)

Comment: Using version 9.3.0.15 like you said fixed the issue. Although on `nuget.org` it says that version 9.3.4.1 is for both .net 2.0 and .net 6 while version 9.3.0.15 is only for .net 2.0 so 9.3.4.1 should also work but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: @FrankMartin Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @JoshMc I created an empty file but didn't create environment variable. Will do it today.

Comment: @JoshMc I tried but it didn't work. I created an empty `mqclient.ini` file in `bin` directory of my application. Then I created a `System Variable` as shown in screenshot https://i.imgur.com/zFHrJmC.png but it didn't work.

Comment: Can the application running in the docker container see that variable?

Comment: I tried it in IIS and not Docker. Not sure how to test this that the application is able to see that variable?